# How to extend the Error interface with generic strings in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

When I try to extend the `Error` interface in Flow to make the `name` property mandatory, Flow doesn't recognise my generic types as strings despite explicitly describing them as strings.

When I write that:

```flow
interface CustomError<A: string, B: string> extends Error {
  message: A;
  name: B;
}
```

I get [these 2 (same) errors](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAUSihygB4BBALmWylAHMAaZAIRrsYD5kIAPSCAAmmZERJRkAbwBQyZHgiZMcBhBoUA3HOQg4imq20BfGUA):

- *Cannot extend `Error` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAUSihygB4BBALmWylAHMAaZAIRrsYD5kIAPSCAAmmZERJRkAbwBQyZHgiZMcBhBoUA3HOQg4imq20BfGUA) with `CustomError` because `A` [2] is incompatible with string [3] in property `message`.*
- *Cannot extend `Error` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAUSihygB4BBALmWylAHMAaZAIRrsYD5kIAPSCAAmmZERJRkAbwBQyZHgiZMcBhBoUA3HOQg4imq20BfGUA) with `CustomError` because `B` [2] is incompatible with string [3] in property `name`.*

What's strange is that it tells me *because `A` [2] is incompatible* when `A` should be described as a `string` right away...

Comment: Why do you need to change `Error` basic members type: `message` and `name`? What you plan to put there beside the string?

Comment: @Alex I actually tried to isolate my issue. Not only I added other properties in my original code but the goal here is to make the `name`, which is natively not a mandatory property, a mandatory one. As for why I need it to be generic: this allows autocompletion to "show" the related strings since there is an error dictionary in the form of a string map object linked to these generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also not clear for me why it doesn't work, however something like this [seems to be ok](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZVgPAIIBc0yWAlgHYDmANNAEKnnU0B80ApgB5JdUAJjGy4s0AN4AoKdGjAUVcvGCosACipg0XUoQY6oYGrqYBKSbLll4ABy4atOswG4r1pAAsKEAHROuaABeaAC3a2gvH19DCGNAkNj48OgAXyl0qSQAT3toQmDoAHJCIugAH2LCAEYitxy8xkKixjLKltq3KVBIGABle2AKADMKYFE8bj4BYThEVEwcPCIGRk4JTIB6Ta9cAHdQrgOBriHR8aWNIrAihiLgItdobYcxBj3cWmgwLBp4HSoSBkuxQByoR2gJzOYwmV1Kd1arhkQA):

```
class CustomError<A: string, B: string> extends Error {

  constructor(name: A, message: B) {
    super(name);
     this.name = name;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

type A = 'A' | 'A1';
type B = 'B' | 'B1';

class SpecificError extends CustomError<A, B> {}

//throw new SpecificError('a', 'c'); //error, wrong argument

throw new SpecificError('A', 'B'); //ok
```

Also, would note that js allows to [throw any expression, not only Error children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), so you might not need to extend `Error` class.